# d3 tree node position

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

How can I position the nodes of a d3 tree chart with variable dimensions?

here is what I have so far, as you can see the positioning is way off

http://jsfiddle.net/cdad0jyz/1/

I have tried to use the separation method:

```
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
        .nodeSize([10,10])
         .separation(function(a, b) {
               var width = 200, // here should be a value calculated for each node
                   distance = width / 2 + 16; 
                   return distance;
           });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you set `x` and `y` on your `text` elements but not on the corresponding `rects`.  To further complicate it, each rect has a random width and height making it difficult to center it on the text.

This is one way to solve it:

```
nodeEnter.append("rect")
    .attr("width",  genRand)  //rectW
    .attr("height", genRand) // rectH
    .attr("x", function(){
        return (rectW / 2) - (d3.select(this).attr('width') / 2);
    })
    .attr("y", function(){
        return (rectH / 2) - (d3.select(this).attr('height') / 2);
    })
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
    return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdad0jyz/2/).